# Using shared C++ library in Idris

Tags: c++, c, linker, ffi, idris

I want to FFI to a third-party C++ library from Idris but I'm getting "undefined symbol". I'm new to C/C++ compilation.

I'm doing this by wrapping the C++ in a pure C layer which I call from Idris. The C++ code is provided as a bunch of `.h` headers and a single `.so` shared library. At the moment I only have one C file, but I may have more later.

Here's the C++ library header include/foo.h

```cpp
#include <some/other/library/header.h>

namespace mynamespace {
  class Foo {
    public:
      Foo();
  }
}
```

and the C wrapper wrapper.cpp

```c
#include <foo.h>

extern "C" {
    struct cFoo;

    using namespace mynamespace;

    struct cFoo* cFoo_new() {
        return reinterpret_cast<cFoo*>(new Foo());
    }
}
```

The shared library is lib/libfoo_ext.so and I'm compiling these with

```
g++ -shared -Iinclude -Llib -lfoo_ext -o libfoo.so wrapper.cpp
```

That runs without errors. Meanwhile, the Idris code is

```
module Foo

import System.FFI

export
Foo : Type
Foo = Struct "cFoo" []

%foreign "C:cFoo_new,libfoo"
export
mkFoo : Foo
```

and I'm calling `mkFoo` in a test file. When I do this I get

```
Exception: (while loading libfoo.so) .../build/exec/_tmpchez_app/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: _ZN17mynamespace6FooC1Ev
```

Comment: Where is the constructor's definition?

Comment: @molbdnilo the actual implementation of `Foo()`? That is, I imagine, in the `.so`. Would that make sense? I'll check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
g++ -shared -Iinclude -Llib -lfoo_ext -o libfoo.so wrapper.cpp
```

is incorrect. Assuming `libfoo_ext` is the 3rd party library which implements `mynamespace::Foo::Foo()`, the link command should be:

```
g++ -shared -Iinclude -Llib -o libfoo.so wrapper.cpp -lfoo_ext
```

The order of libraries and sources on the link line [matters](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking), yours is wrong.

Comment: nice, thanks. Now it shows a different, but more promising error "Exception: (while loading libfoo.so) libfoo_ext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I'll look into that

Comment: @joel For that you need to either set `RPATH` properly (better) at link time with `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib`, or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` worked. I'll have a look at `-rpath`. Where would that go in the `g++` call?

Comment: @joel Anywhere on the link line. E.g. `g++ -shared ... -lfoo_ext -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/directory/in/which/libfoo_ext.so/resides`.